# SublimeText 3 freezes on large files

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

When I load a very large log file in sublimetext 3, about 200,000+ lines, the editor freezes when I search.

As soon as I open the search dialog box it starts to become unresponsize.

Is this just a shortcoming of the editor, or are there settings that might help alleviate this problem?

EDIT: I have discovered that by default log files are not indexed in sublime.

```
// index_exclude_patterns indicate which files won't be indexed.
"index_exclude_patterns": ["*.log"],
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to disable indexing?

```
"index_files": false
```

You can also exclude certain files from being indexed:

```
"index_exclude_patterns": ["*.iso", "*.exe"],
```

Comment: What benefits does indexed files provide? EDIT: index_files : false made no difference.

Comment: Afaik, files are being indexed so you can use the "Goto Anything" feature.

Comment: Not the case, read my edit.

Comment: Every text-editor should slow down when working with huge files, though there might be editors that handle them better than others. So, have ever opened that file somewhere else? Does it perform better? I also wonder whether a text-editor handles large files better when there's no syntax highlighting.